# How do you space the contents of a table while sending a Discord message (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am currently making a Discord generator bot, but I can't find out how to space the generated values. It does print out the table, but it doesn't generate a new message row for each key. I am trying to make it send the table, but also make a new message row for each generated key. Here is my code:

```
    let keys = []

      message.channel.send(`I have sent you ${amount} Synapse X keys in your DMS`);
      for ( var i = 0; i < amount; i++ ) {
        let synapse = synapsekeysbared(8)
        let synapse2 = synapsekeysbared(12)
        let synapse3 = synapsekeys(4)
        let synapse4 = synapsekeys(4)
        let synapse5 = synapsekeys(4)
    keys.push(`${synapse}-${synapse3}-${synapse4}-${synapse5}-${synapse2}`)
    }
    message.author.send(`${keys}`);
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```js
keys.join('\n')
```

This will join every element by a line break. For example:

```js
var lines = ['Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3'];
console.log(lines.join('\n'));
```